# Fast scrollbar with indicator for GridView in Material Design style

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, material-design, android-cardview

I have a grid, which consist of many cards ordered by alphabet.

I want to achieve behavior similar to standard Android clock app. I.e I need a fast scrollbar with indicator in Material Design for my `GridView`.

[image]

**Any ideas? Libraries?**

Any help is truly appreciated. Alex. P.S. Sorry for my English:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. There is a library for that: https://github.com/danoz73/RecyclerViewFastScroller

So I guess it's the best time to start using RecyclerView :)

[image]